# Where can I find free cervical MRI files and cervical CT angiography files?

Tags: research, mri, radiology

I would like to research cervical MRI and CT-angiography files of different people to understand more about cervical MRI and CT-angiography.

I've only been able to find some other MRIs and CTs here: https://demo.softneta.com/search.html

But no cervical MRIs or CT-angiographies.

Where could I find or download these files?

P.S. If someone has the same query, here are some collections I've found:

- https://boxdicom.com/samples.html (different MRIs, including
  cervical)
- https://www.dicomlibrary.com/meddream/?study=1.3.6.1.4.1.44316.6.102.1.20210804165813624.36372704986493662224 (c-spine, t-spine MRI)
- https://www.embodi3d.com/search/ (you can
  search CTA and probably everything else there)

Comment: Have you tried a google image search? I just entered 'cervical mri' in google image search and found thousands of examples. I don't know which ones are freely available and would be useful to you, but it's a good place to start.

Comment: @CareyGregory yeah, I saw a lot of images in Google. But I'm looking specifically for DICOM files, because I want to look at them in a special program, to be able, for example, to see the same areas in different projections, and see where the slice is on a different projection. And be able to access each slice in the study for research.

Comment: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place to go, otherwise look for papers written in your area that cite open data sources. These sorts of data sets are not trivial to create - they rely on private patient data, they're expensive, the files are potentially huge. There's not a lot of motivation, outside promotion of open data, to provide these to people.

Comment: @BryanKrause thanks. Dicomlibrary website has a lot of uploaded studies, but they are unlisted, so one can only see them if they have the link. I think many people wouldn't mind sharing their anonymized files. I would definitely not mind my anonymized medical data to be used in researches or medical communities / universities, if I had an option to share it somewhere. I'll check opendata